# Selecionar Opção de Combo Select a partir de novo Atributo

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Quero selecionar aquele option que contém o atributo uf, de acordo com o uf.

```
<select data-placeholder="" class="chosen-select" id="f_state" name="f_state" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">:: Selecione ::</option>
    <option value="5" code="AC">Acre</option>
    <option value="17" code="AL">Alagoas</option>
    <option value="9" code="AP">Amapá</option>
    <option value="6" code="AM">Amazonas</option>
    <option value="19" code="BA">Bahia</option>
    <option value="13" code="CE">Ceará</option>
    <option value="27" code="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
    <option value="21" code="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
    <option value="28" code="XX">Estado Temporário</option>
    <option value="26" code="GO">Goiás</option>
    <option value="11" code="MA">Maranhão</option>
    <option value="25" code="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
    <option value="24" code="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
    <option value="20" code="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
    <option value="8" code="PA">Pará</option>
    <option value="15" code="PB">Paraíba</option>
    <option value="3" code="PR">Paraná</option>
    <option value="16" code="PE">Pernambuco</option>
    <option value="12" code="PI">Piauí</option>
    <option value="22" code="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="14" code="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
    <option selected="" value="1" code="RS"> Rio Grande do Sul</option>
    <option value="4" code="RO">Rondônia</option>
    <option value="7" code="RR">Roraima</option>
    <option value="2" code="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
    <option value="23" code="SP">São Paulo</option>
    <option value="18" code="SE">Sergipe</option>
    <option value="10" code="TO">Tocantins</option>                 
</select>
```

O seguinte código funciona:

**$('#f_state').val( $('option:contains("'+dados.estado+'")').val() );**

Porém, eu nao tenho dados.estado, e sim dados.uf

**$('#f_state').val( $('option:contains("'+dados.uf+'")').val() );**

Por isso adicionei o atributo code="uf"

para de alguma forma buscar ele e seleciona-lo em uma busca de cep

Mas nao consigo acessar o option de atributo code = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**resolvido**

let estado = $('#f_state').find("[code='" + dados.uf + "']").text().trim();
        $('#f_state').val( $('option:contains("'+estado+'")').val() );
```